# Getting selectedvalue of radiobuttonlist in gridview on selectedindexchanged

Tags: asp.net, gridview, radiobuttonlist, selectedvalue, selectedindexchanged

There is a radiobuttonlist in a gridview. I want to do something with the selectedvalue of which radiobuttonlist's selectedindexchanged.

But it's giving the old value always. For example the first item is selected when page load. If I click the second item, its still giving the first item's value.

My codes, in aspx file:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="cezaDS" >
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Öğrenci Bilgileri" SortExpression="SINIF">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lbSiraNo" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SIRA_NO") %>'></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ADI_SOYADI") %>'></asp:Label><br />
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OKUL_NO") %>'></asp:Label><br />
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BOLUM") %>'></asp:Label><br />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SINIF") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ceza Türü ve Aldığı Zaman" SortExpression="DONEM">
<ItemTemplate>
Ceza Türü: <b><asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CEZA_TURU") %>'></asp:Label></b><br />
Cezayı Aldığı Sınıf: <b><asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CEZA_ALDIGI_SINIF") %>'></asp:Label></b><br />
Cezayı Aldığı Öğretim Yılı: <b><asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DONEM") %>'></asp:Label></b>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:BoundField DataField="ILGILI_MADDE" HeaderText="İlgili Madde" SortExpression="ILGILI_MADDE" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Kararınız">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdList" runat="server" 
AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdList_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Value="Kaldırılsın">Kaldırılsın</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="Kaldırılmasın">Kaldırılmasın</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In cs file:

```
    protected void rdList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((RadioButtonList)sender).NamingContainer);
    Label cezaSiraNo = (Label)(row.FindControl("lbSiraNo"));
    RadioButtonList clickedList= (RadioButtonList)sender;
    string x = clickedList.SelectedValue;
    //...
```

Here x variable is taking the wrong value.

Comment: plz share complete code

Comment: I dont think it's necessary but I've updated the question. For example at the moment first item is selected but I am clicking the second element. x variable's value is being the first item's value..

Comment: I tried above code and this is working as expected.